# How to modify existing timeaxis in xarray?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have monthly ocean temperature data from 1940/01 to 2021/12. The temperature has dimensions (lat,lon, time, and depth). But, the array of time axis has 'dtype=float32', and even it's not showing the dates correctly.
Time
array([ 1.940010e+05, -1.790609e+00, -1.788719e+00, ..., -1.651860e+00,
-1.794639e+00, -1.808418e+00], dtype=float32)

How to modify this time axis? Please let me know.

Comment: It looks like its a formatting issue. Try converting each element of the column into a datetime object using the datetime module. You will want to use the method datetime.strptime(). https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Okay let me check...thank you

Answer (score 0):

Handling of datetime is one of the main/basic issue that comes when we're using climate/daily data. It's always good to follow the cftime(climate and forecast) convention(theres a module named on that too) while handling such data. pandas datetime function is more suited to this scenario since you already know the origin date, and the end date.
you can create your own time axis.

```
import pandas as pd
start_date = '1940-01-01'
end_date = '2021-12-01'
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='M')
```

The other method is using datetime library. But that involves an assumption that months are about 30 days, which isn't true.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start_date = datetime(1940,01,01)
date_range = [start_date+timedelat(days=30*i) for i in range(len(temperature["time"]))
```

Note: the first method is more precise.